# How to derive the equation for sinusoidal fringe pattern?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, laser

I have this equation for the sinusoidal fringe pattern:

$I_1(x,y)=I'(x,y)+I''(x,y)\cos\phi(x,y)$

and want to know the derivation of this equation.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We work with scalar fields. For example, if we have light in one polarization, then the field distribution can be approximately characterized by a complex scalar field $E(x,\,y,\,z)$ (which can stand to the transverse electric field component).

Suppose we now have two light beams, in the same polarization, and we overlap them. Suppose their scalar field representations are $E_1(x,\,y,\,z)$ and $E_2(x,\,y,\,z)$. Then, since Maxwell's equations and the wave equation are linear, the total field is simply the superposition of the two.

$$E = E_1(x,\,y,\,z) + E_2(x,\,y,\,z)$$

So now, what is the intensity of this field? Clearly it is:

$$|E_1(x,\,y,\,z)|^2 + |E_2(x,\,y,\,z)|^2 + 2\, \mathrm{Re}\left(E_1(x,\,y,\,z)\,E_2(x,\,y,\,z)^\ast\right)$$

By representing the fields in polar ($r\,e^{i\,\phi}$) notation, where $r$ and $\phi$ are functions of the co-ordinates, you should be able to rework the above into the form you are seeking.